# TeXstudio changed encoding

Tags: texstudio, input-encodings

I wrote my text using UTF-8 encoding, however, TeXstudio somehow changed this and I cannot find the way to return my text in readable form. Is it possible at all or should I die now?

Comment: before experimenting on anything make sure you have a `file.tex.backup` made from original file. I suppose texstudio would detect your encoding and suggests a right encoding to view properly, incase it's different from the default one in editor. Don't save the file in wrong encoding, since editors does not change encoding, stick to UTF-8 always on all editors and preferably use one editors on all machines/OS.

Answer (score 10):

First select in the menu:

`Edit->Setup Encoding...`

This will open a dialog. There you select *UTF8* and click *View With*.

[image]

For the future you can put the following lines at the top of your latex documents, of course you can adjust them as you need.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX spellcheck = de_DE
```

TeXstudio will then know, what encoding the file is.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom bar, there is a menu on the right side, where you can change the encoding (a bit left of the bookmark symbols).

Also, with the help of `iconv` (Linux) or [CsCvt](http://www.cscvt.de/) (Windows), you can also convert encodings of files.

Comment: This does not help to return my text.

Comment: Is your TeX source unreadable or your PDF document?

Comment: TeX source, of course.

Comment: If you have Linux, you could use `iconv`, on Windows you can try [CsCvt](http://www.cscvt.de/) to convert the encoding.