# Undefined control sequence. \begin{document} when compiling via Xelatex

Tags: errors, xetex, templates, texstudio, font-encodings

This question has been asked several times before, but I think every individual's experience is a bit different. 
I have tried 3 latex templates, all of them giving the same error. Just for a reproducible example, you can play with this one from [Claud D.Park](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV).

Error while compiling using Xelatex is the same, pdf appears to be generated but has an unexpected number sequence on the top.

I have also changed the encoding to UTF-8 as suggested by others [via this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154278/texstudio-changed-encoding).

I think it's something small, but I am unable to figure it out.
Log is also attached.

> ! Undefined control sequence. __um_set_big_operator:nnn
>   ...r_gset_active_eq:nN 
>                                                     {#3}__um_tmpa: __um_set_... l.73 \begin{document}
>                         The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it
>   (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. __um_set_big_operator:nnn
>   ...r_gset_active_eq:nN 
>                                                     {#3}__um_tmpa: __um_set_... l.73 \begin{document}

Full Log : http://www.filedropper.com/cv_3

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but this looks like like an incompatibility between versions of `fontspec` and `expl3`. What TeX distribution are you using, and is it completely up to date?  If you're using Linux I recommend installing TeXLive directly without using the Linux package manager. This will allow you to keep the distribution updated much more easily.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the followup. Its `TeXstudio 2.10.2 (hg 5506:2a97a460a6ee)` on `Mac OS X El Captain v 10.11.2`. I reckon its upto date.

Comment: Ok. But TeXStudio is the editor, not the distribution. Since I'm assuming you have installed MacTeX, then in the TeX folder in Applications there should be a TeXLive Utility. Use this to update your distribution.

Comment: Thank you Alan, that was it. Please move your comment to an answer, so I can accept it.

I replaced the current TexLive utility with the new beta version supported for `El Captain` available here.
https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting is indicative of an incompatibility between `fontspec` and the `expl3` packages, which can be caused by your TeX distribution not being fully up-to-date.

See this answer for details on how to do that:

- [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/2693)

But looking more carefully at the log file, there are other issues that you should deal with. The log shows that you have loaded the `inputenc` package, which should not be loaded if you are using XeLaTeX. See:

- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/2693)

Finally, I notice that you have installed BasicTeX (a small subset of the full MacTeX distribution). Although this saves space in the initial download, as a beginner, I think you would be better off with the full distribution, since this will reduce dramatically the headaches associated with missing packages.