I am using texstudio and am getting chinese characters
My file is about four pages. It ran under Ubuntu. I copied tex file to flash drive. Two copies. One loads as Chinese characters, but compile fine. Down loaded to windows 10. One is a file of Chinese characters and compiles to English pdf.  English character will not compile and ends with error message but no error in log file. What is going on?

welcome! please think about your question from our point of view for a moment. would you expect somebody to be able to answer it based on the information provided? could you give additional details which might help somebody trying to help you? questions which immediately occur to me: what is supposed to be in the file? is it a specific error or just windows complaining about the state of the world? what encoding does your file use? if you take the files back to ubuntu, do they display correctly? what does English character refer to? are the Chinese characters supposed to compile to eng pdf?

it sounds like you have a correctly encoded tex file (possibliy in UTF-8) but your editor is set to use a different encoding probably a legacy windows codepage.  I don't use texstudio but probably this answer is for a duplicate question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154278/texstudio-changed-encoding
